# How to separately identify request in facebook?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I am developing an app which contains facebook login and i need to fetch my details and my friend's detail while login. I used the below codes for that:

```
    - (void)fbDidLogin
    {
        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self]; 
        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];

    }

    - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
    {
     NSLog(@"%@",result);
    }
```

Its not working properly.Can i able to separately identify the request in didLoad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before getting your friends list, you have to make sure you have logged in succesfully. do it one at a time.

```
 - (void)fbDidLogin
    {
        apiCall = logInUser;
        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self]; 

    } 

   - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
        switch (apiCall) {
            case logInUser:
            {
              if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
                }
                if ([result objectForKey:@"name"]) {
                   //login success
                    apiCall = getFriends;
                   [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
                }
            }break;
            case getFriends:{
               //success  
             }break;
              .
              .
              .
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. What is this apiCall ?

Comment: apiCall is just an int. declare it in your header